# Problem connection with local mongodb from nodejs: [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating nodejs server and connect it to local mongodb on EC2 instance. Connection with mongodb is error.

I've tried it on local machine and it ran well. I've tried use MongoAtlas successfully. But when try on EC2 instance, it shows the error message:

> telegram-bot-02@0.0.0 start /home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01
>   node ./bin/www
>
> mongdb://127.0.0.1:27017/telegram
>   MongoDb connection error { MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
>       at parseConnectionString (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:412:21)
>       at connect (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:180:3)
>       at connectOp (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:284:3)
>       at executeOperation (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
>       at MongoClient.connect (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:168:10)
>       at Promise (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:521:12)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:518:19)
>       at Mongoose.connect (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:270:15)
>       at Object. (/home/ec2-user/workspace/rep01/app.js:16:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>     name: 'MongoParseError',
>     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

I tried to reinstall mongodb, but not work. Mongodb version is v4.0.5
Please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: can you add code as well with your connection string
with this error, i can only tell you which connection string you have provided for connection is not valid means there mongo not running

Comment: I used 'mongo' and it works. Here's the code: `const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoDb = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
mongoose.connect(
  mongoDb,
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDb connection error"));`. Connection string: "mongodb://localhost:27017/telegram"

Answer (score 3):

Try this, This works for me, I got same erros because i tried to connect in wrong way.
My previous code that produce the " 'MongoParseError', [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }" error is -

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/27017/creative-ideas', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Mongodb connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The corrected code is:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/creative_ideas', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Mongodb connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Di
scover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the Mo
ngoClient constructor.

so the correct code is

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/usercrud', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  })
.then(() => console.log("Mongodb connected"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this [link](https://codesquery.com/connect-node-js-with-mongodb-using-mongoose/) for instructions to connect your node.js with the MongoDB.

On example is

```
//with using the promise
mongoose.connect(uri,options).then(() => {
  //connection established successfully
}).catch(error){
  //catch any error during the initial connection
}
```

Comment: Link answers aren't ideal, if the link changes the answer is no longer relevant. If providing a link it's good practice to copy any meaning details into your answer.